# Set a Model's Attribute Through Constructor

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection and two models;

#### The two models

```js
var typeDefault = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        type: ""
    },
    constructor: function (attrs, options) {
        var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(attrs);
        this.attributes = parsedResponse;
    },
});

var typeMessage = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        user: "user",
        text: "text"
    },
    constructor: function (attrs, options) {
        var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(attrs);
        this.attributes = parsedResponse;
    },
});
```

#### The Collection

```js
var chatWebSocketCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        console.log("chatWebSocketCollection initialized");
    },
    model: function (attrs, options) {
        var type = JSON.parse(attrs);
        if (type.type == "message") {
            return new typeMessage(attrs, options);
        } else {
            return new typeDefault(attrs, options);
        }
    }
});
```

I wanted the constructor to set the attributes of the model according to the JSON object parsed from the 'attrs' of the collection. So I can `listenTo` a `change` event from a view.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the constructor function over the initialize function?

Comment: I opted to use constructor because whenever I initialize the model to be used for the listenTo, I get an 'undefined' error. I just started learning Backbone, still figuring things out. But I changed my app's logic, thanks anyway. Just curious though if you know the answer, I might use it in the future or someone else. @jmfolds